# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'GIDConfiguration' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to create a google sign in page and I have a signInModel that has a few errors that i need help solving
the errors are on the line
`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: configuration, presenting: rootViewController) { \[unowned self\] user, error in`
the errors are Cannot convert value of type 'GIDConfiguration' to expected argument type 'UIViewController', Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'String?', Extra trailing closure passed in call

and the line
`guard let authentication = user?.authentication, let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }`
the error is Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'authentication'

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Part one
    enum signInState {
        case signedIn
        case signedOut
    }

    @Published var state: signInState = .signedOut

    func signIn() {
        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.hasPreviousSignIn() {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { [unowned self] user, error in
                authenticateUser(for: user, with: error)
            }
        } else {
            guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

            let configuration = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)

            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
            guard let rootViewController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController else { return }

            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: configuration, presenting: rootViewController) { [unowned self] user, error in
                authenticateUser(for: user, with: error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func authenticateUser(for user: GIDGoogleUser?, with error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let idToken = user?.authentication?.idToken else { return }

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: user?.authentication?.accessToken ?? "")

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { [unowned self] (_, error) in
            if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.state = .signedIn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: configuration, presenting: rootViewController)
```

has been updated to

```swift
signIn(withPresenting: UIViewController)
```

and configuration part will be handle in plist.

1. Use it like that

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController) { [unowned self] result, error in
                authenticateUser(for: result.user, with: error)
            }
```

2. Add client id in plist.

```
<key>GIDClientID</key>
<string>CLIENTID</string>
```

**Note:-**  it returns `GIDSignInResult` not `GIDGoogleUser`